# FlexSlider video iframe problems in Safari

Tags: jquery, iframe, embedding, vimeo

I'm using the [Flexslider](http://flex.madebymufffin.com/) and I have a slider with an embedded Vimeo video in an iframe, and then the rest of the slider is filled with pictures that are the same size as the video.

The slider+video works great in most browser EXCEPCT Safari. When Safari loads the slider, the video seems to be offset a little bit in a weird location. The video playback is somewhat choppy, and the controls are unresponsive. This is very frustrating because the slider works great in all other browsers, and the documentation for FlexSlider says it supports all HTML elements.

Is there something I can do to get this video to play properly in Safari?

Here is my code

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
   <li>
     <div id="iframeContainer">
       <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/35534572?title=0&amp;api=1&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="960" height="540" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
     </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <img src="MOTOROLA_BTS_01.jpg" />
   </li>
   <li>
      <img src="MOTOROLA_BTS_02.jpg" />    
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
.flex-container a:active,
.flexslider a:active {outline: none;}
.slides,
.flex-control-nav,
.flex-direction-nav {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;} 

/* FlexSlider Necessary Styles
*********************************/ 
.flexslider {width: 960px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.flexslider .slides > li {display: none;-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;} /* Hide the slides before the JS is loaded. Avoids image jumping */
.flexslider .slides img {max-width: 100%; display: block;}
.flex-pauseplay span {text-transform: capitalize;}

/* Clearfix for the .slides element */
.slides:after {content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0;} 
html[xmlns] .slides {display: block;} 
* html .slides {height: 1%;}

/* No JavaScript Fallback */
/* If you are not using another script, such as Modernizr, make sure you
 * include js that eliminates this class on page load */
.no-js .slides > li:first-child {display: block;}

.flex-direction-nav li a {width: 60px; height: 60px; margin: -13px 0 0; display: block; position: absolute; top: 50%; cursor: pointer; text-indent: -9999px;}
.flex-direction-nav li .next {background-image:url(Arrow_02_B.png);margin-top:-300px;margin-left:900px;}
.flex-direction-nav li .prev {background-image:url(Arrow_02_A.png);margin-top:-300px;}
.flex-direction-nav li .disabled {opacity: .3; filter:alpha(opacity=30); cursor: default;}


#iframeContainer{
    width:960px;
    height:540px;
}
```

EDIT: I put an embedded video outside of the slider on the page, and it isn't even showing up in Safari. I get a little sliver of where I can see a bit of the video. Again, it shows up properly in all other browsers.

EDIT: More troubleshooting. I put the slider and the video side by side. The video still breaks in Safari. HOWEVER, if I don't initialize the slideshow, the video works fine. The video is not inside of the slide show, it's totally seperate. But when I turn the slideshow back on, the video breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else runs into this issue, it looks like a video feature has been added to flexslider. I was having the same issue described here, but after turning the video flag to true upon initializing the flexslider, the videos started working.

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",     
    video: true
});
```

On a side note, The video flag makes the slider less responsive when used on a touch device. It still works, but it has a delay when trying to slide to the next image/video.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same problem. The issue is due to transform3d bug in safari.
Refer to below link for complete issue and fix.

https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/88

Summarizing the Fix:

> Download the latest version of v1.8 and use the property `useCSS: false.` It will remove the >use of translate3d which causes these video errors in webkit browsers.

Though its a very old post. Hope it helps someone in future :)